# React: Not able to render routes to a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

This is my Navbar component,

```
const Navbar = () => (

        <nav className="navbarLogged">

            <ul>
                <li><NavLink to="/">Trending</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/live">Live</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/fanzone">Fanzone</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/lets-play">Let's Play</NavLink></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>


);

export default Navbar
```

I want to render four separate components inside a different component, in this way.

```
const CoreSection = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <section className="coreSectionLogged">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Feeds title="Home"/>}/>
                <Route path="/live" render={() => <LiveScore title="Livescore"/>}/>
                <Route path="/fanzone" render={() => <Fanzone title="Fanzone"/>}/>
                <Route path="/lets-play" render={() => <Quiz title="quiz"/>}/>
            </Switch>

        </section>
    </BrowserRouter>

);
```

This doesn't render the components. When I run this, I get the following error,

```
You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
```

This can be fixed if I wrap my Routes inside a BrowserRouter, like this,

```
const Navbar = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <nav className="navbarLogged">
            <ul>
                <li><NavLink to="/">Trending</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/live">Live</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/fanzone">Fanzone</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/lets-play">Let's Play</NavLink></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </BrowserRouter>


);
```

In this case the error goes away, but the routing still doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `NavLink` component has to be within `Router`.

It will work if you wrap `<BrowserRouter>` around your top component enclosing all `<Switch> <Route> <NavLink>` and all the other that's associated with routing into a single router - in this case `<BrowserRouter>`